# How to include screenshots in HTMLTestRunner report?

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, python-unittest

I'm using Python / Selenium / unittest / HTMLTestRunner

I would like to include screenshot to every test that have failed for test suite.

With this it run test suite and create report

```
h = HTMLTestRunner(template="tests/reports/template/report_template.html", combine_reports=True, report_name="MyReport", add_timestamp=True).run(suite)
```

Here `tearDown` create screenshot and close test. If suite contains more tests, then new browser opens and continue with next test steps and at the end again create screenshot and closes and so on till last test.

```
@classmethod
def tearDown(cls):
now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
cls.driver.get_screenshot_as_file('reports/screenshot-%s.png' % now)
cls.driver.quit()
```

How I can take correct screenshot and put it in report under test that created that screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

I also facing the same problem and here's my approach based on [this](https://github.com/oldani/HtmlTestRunner/issues/40).

In the `tearDown`,

```
@classmethod
def tearDown(cls):
     for method, error in self.outcome.errors:
          if error: # Screenshot will be taken if there's an error raised
               now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
               name = 'reports/screenshot-%s.png' % now
               cls.driver.get_screenshot_as_file(name)
               print(name)

     cls.driver.quit()
```

Then in your `report_template.html` which I assume based on [this template](https://github.com/oldani/HtmlTestRunner/blob/master/HtmlTestRunner/template/report_template.html), make some adjustment in this HTML code.

```
{%- if (test_case.stdout or test_case.err or test_case.err) and test_case.outcome != test_case.SKIP %}
<tr style="display:none;">
 <td class="col-xs-9" colspan="3">
   {%- if test_case.err %}<p style="color:maroon;">{{ test_case.err[0].__name__ }}: {{ test_case.err[1] }}</p>{% endif %}
   {%- if test_case.err %}<p style="color:maroon;">{{ test_case.test_exception_info }}</p>{% endif %}
   {%- if test_case.stdout %}<p>{{ test_case.stdout }}</p>{% endif %}
   <img src="your path to the image here" />
  </td>
 </tr>
{%- endif %}
```

Comment: does this work? what specifically goes in here:  <img src="your path to the image here" />?

Comment: @l Pratama - any help would be greatly appreciated!!!